# Optimizing min function for changing lists

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I am dealing with a problem where I need to keep track of the minimum number in a list. However, this list is constantly diminishing, say like from a million elements to a single element. I was looking for a way to avoid checking the minimum value everytime I got a one element smaller list. Like keeping track of the minimum element and if it is removed the next minimum becomes the minimum. I want to accomplish this in linear time.(It should be achievable given the mechanics of the problem)

What I thought of since I started that, I can use `collections Counter` to count elements in the list. Then I find the minimum(already `O(2*n)`), and everytime I remove an element, I subtract 1 from the value of the dictionary key. However when the minimum number's count is depleted, I would still require to find the second minimum element so it could replace it.

Please help me find a solution to this. I would say this is an interesting problem.

Comment: wait you begin with some list and you're inserting and removing items on the fly ? and you need to keep track of min number

Comment: Just removing in this case, you can assume that which element I am removing is predetermined.

Comment: can numbers in list be repeated

Comment: Yes, as I said I thought of using `Counter` which would have no purpose if all the elements were single.

Comment: There's no linear time algorithm for this, since you can use it to sort the input list by repeatedly removing the minimum element. But what _exactly_ are the requirements? You say you have a list and are diminishing elements from it. How are you removing elements? Is it always from one end or the other? Can you show some representative code for what you're doing with the slow min calculation that you want to replace?

Comment: @PaulHankin I found a better way than using a list in my problem. However if you want to think on the subject, the elements were being removed from the left site of the list always. You can imagine it like you are iterating over one list, and you need the minimum value from the current element to last element (discarding already passed elements, which I was doing with removing leftside elements). I found a nice enough way of finding that value. I would love to share it if it interests you.

Comment: It's a well-known problem. You can run through the original list (from right-to-left if you're popping from the left) and build up a stack of the minimum-so-far found element. When you remove the current min, you pop it off the stack. This is O(n) time to create the stack in the first place, and O(1) to find the current minimum. The size of the stack is n in the worst case and ~= log n on average assuming the list is a random permutation of distinct values.

Comment: (Note: removing an element from the left of a list is not an efficient operation, but perhaps you're doing this logically rather than literally).

Comment: @PaulHankin Thank you for your reply. However I must say It felt good discovering this myself :) (At first I was doing it literally, but when I was explaining to you, it was logically. And when I was doing it literally, I was using deque)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your program would take some time to sort that list

```
a = [10,9,10,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,1,1,0] # you're just removing 
a = sorted(a) #sort ascending

# then you remove stuff from your list
# but always a[0] is minimum element

min = a[0] #you must be careful, there must be at least one item so check that before 
#getting the min
```

So there is no need for searching it every time

Comment: I thought of doing this too, however sorting is also another heavy work for a large list. Well I guess `nlogn` is as good as any. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: But sorting it once is better than touching it every time :)

Comment: Well I ended up sorting and after using deque for making edge pops faster. I forgot to mention I was removing edge items from the list.

Comment: It is obviously better, but I can't help saying that I am trying to write something even faster. If it is possible in theory of course :D

Comment: If you so much need speed, than I'd use compiled language :)